# compare grep output for same string from two files

Tags: linux, bash

I have 3 files:
1 contains list of strings to check for
2 contains new prices
3 contains prices that would need to be replaced if these prices change in file #2

Example:

file #1
    item1
    item2

file #2

```
item1cost100
item2cost200
```

file# #3

```
item1cost101
item2cost199
```

After running the script, the file #3 should be updated

file# #3

```
item1cost100
item2cost200
```

file #2 and #3 contain a lot of entries but only entries in file #1 need to be checked and if different written to file #3

I only got as far as comparing the two files for 1 string, i am not sure how to loop through contents of file #1 and how to write the changes to file #3
I started working with sed command and got stuck not knowing how to unwrap variables

Here is what I got

```
item="item1"
itemold=$(cat file2 | grep item1)
echo $itemold
itemnew=$(cat file3 | grep item1)
echo $itemnew
echo $item
if [ $itemold = $itemnew ]; then
echo "MATCH!"
else
echo "NO MATCH!"
fi
```

Comment: no, they could be all over the place in all 3 files

Comment: No spaces or other oddities though? Just those lines, in any particular order, one entry per line? Also, how many entries per file typically?

Comment: no spaces. however, it needs to be able to accept the variables as links too having : // and / and no order. One entry per line only

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cut -d' ' -f1 file1 > a
grep `cat a` file2 > b
grep `cat a` file3 > c
sed s/`cat c`/`cat b`/g file3 > d
cut -d' ' -f2 file1 > a
grep `cat a` file2 > b
grep `cat a` file3 > c
sed s/`cat c`/`cat b`/g d > file3
```

This takes care of the case you gave. It could be generalized.